# Import Relational Xml Data into sql server 2012

Tags: sql, xml, import, sql-server-2012

```
<Order>
  <AmazonOrderID>1111-222-33</AmazonOrderID>
  <MerchantOrderID>111-222-33</MerchantOrderID>
  <PurchaseDate>2014-08-03T18:11:11+00:00</PurchaseDate>
  <LastUpdatedDate>2014-08-03T18:11:14+00:00</LastUpdatedDate>
  <OrderStatus>Pending</OrderStatus>
  <SalesChannel>Amazon.in</SalesChannel>
  <FulfillmentData>
    <FulfillmentChannel>Amazon</FulfillmentChannel>
    <ShipServiceLevel>Standard</ShipServiceLevel>
    <Address>
      <City>bangalore</City>
      <State>karnataka</State>
      <PostalCode>560038</PostalCode>
      <Country>IN</Country>
    </Address>
  </FulfillmentData>
  <OrderItem>
    <ASIN>B00AW9A53Q</ASIN>
    <SKU>SiM13</SKU>
    <ItemStatus>Unshipped</ItemStatus>
    <ProductName>Chicco 500ml Body Lotion</ProductName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <ItemPrice>
      <Component>
        <Type>Principal</Type>
        <Amount currency="INR">390.0</Amount>
      </Component>
    </ItemPrice>
  </OrderItem>
</Order>
```

how can i import this xml data into relational tables. i have 2 tables one is Order and another is items.i wanna insert below mentioned line in order table with  as primary key.

```
   <AmazonOrderID>111-222-333</AmazonOrderID>
  <MerchantOrderID>1111-3333-444</MerchantOrderID>
  <PurchaseDate>2014-08-03T18:11:11+00:00</PurchaseDate>
  <LastUpdatedDate>2014-08-03T18:11:14+00:00</LastUpdatedDate>
  <OrderStatus>Pending</OrderStatus>
  <SalesChannel>Amazon.in</SalesChannel>
```

and  order item in items table with amazonid as foreign key

```
 <OrderItem>
    <ASIN>B00AW9A53Q</ASIN>
    <SKU>SiM13</SKU>
    <ItemStatus>Unshipped</ItemStatus>
    <ProductName>Chicco 500ml Body Lotion</ProductName>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <ItemPrice>
      <Component>
        <Type>Principal</Type>
        <Amount currency="INR">390.0</Amount>
      </Component>
    </ItemPrice>
  </OrderItem>
</Order>
```

please anyone can provide solution for this..i will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your XML in a SQL variable of type `XML` called `@Input`, you could use this for the first part of your question:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Order(AmazonOrderID, MerchantOrderID, 
                      PurchaseDate, LastUpdateDate, OrderStatus, SalesChannel)
   SELECT
      AmazonOrderID = @input.value('(/Order/AmazonOrderID)[1]', 'varchar(25)'),
      MerchantOrderID = @input.value('(/Order/MerchantOrderID)[1]', 'varchar(25)'),
      PurchaseDate = @input.value('(/Order/PurchaseDate)[1]', 'datetimeoffset'),
      LastUpdatedDate = @input.value('(/Order/LastUpdatedDate)[1]', 'datetimeoffset'),
      OrderStatus = @input.value('(/Order/OrderStatus)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
      SalesChannel = @input.value('(/Order/SalesChannel)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
```

I'm not quite clear what you want to do with the second part of your question - are there potentially multiple `<OrderItem>` entries? What do you want to do about the nested `<ItemPrice>` structure?

And what do you mean by *amazonid as foreign key* - what `AmazonId` are you referring to?